# Modular equation for a quotient of eta functions

Tags: special-functions, modular-forms

In [this article](http://wain.mi.ras.ru/zw/Beukers-Asterisque1987.pdf) at page $4$ F. Beukers introduces a function $$y(\tau) = \frac{\eta^{8}(6\tau)\eta^{4}(\tau)}{\eta^{8}(2\tau)\eta^{4}(3\tau)}\tag{1}$$ where $\tau$ is a complex number with positive imaginary part and Dedekind's eta function $\eta(\tau)$ is defined by $$\eta(\tau) = e^{\pi i\tau/12}\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - e^{2\pi in\tau})\tag{2}$$ Beukers then mentions that the function $y(\tau)$ satisfies the following equation $$y\Big(\frac{-1}{6\tau}\Big) = \frac{y(\tau) - 1/9}{y(\tau) - 1}\tag{3}$$

But I can't check that. I have already tried to use the functional equation for eta function $$\eta(-1/\tau)=\sqrt{-i\tau}\;\eta(\tau)\tag{4}$$ but this doesn't work. Has this something to do with Beukers remark "$y(\tau)$ generates the field of modular functions"? But why does $y(\tau)$ generate this field?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It is better to write at least some details about equation $(1)$. Also mention the definition of $\eta$ function and $y(\tau)$. BTW I did some calculation and it appears that this is related to modular equation between $\eta(\tau), \eta(2t), \eta(3t), \eta(6t)$. A proof would not be easy. I need to check some references to see if it can be done in simple manner.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: It seems this functional equation belongs to a family. Kindly see this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/261349/some-nice-functional-equations-for-q-continued-fractions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I am not so much familiar with the theory of modular forms, I am offering a solution which uses theory of theta functions and their link with elliptic integrals. With this approach the functional relation of $y(\tau)$ is transformed into a modular equation of degree $3$ which can be independently verified using the theory of modular equations.

---

Let $\tau$ be a complex number with positive imaginary part so that $q = e^{2\pi i\tau}$ satisfies $|q| < 1$. The Dedekind $\eta$ function is defined as $$\eta(\tau) = e^{\pi i\tau/12}\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - e^{2\pi in\tau}) = q^{1/24}\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{n}) = 2^{-1/6}\sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi}}k^{1/12}k'^{1/3}\tag{1}$$ where $k, k', K$ associated with nome $q$. Further we have $$\eta(2\tau) = q^{1/12}\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{2n}) = 2^{-1/3}\sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi}}(kk')^{1/6}\tag{2}$$ Now let $l,l', L$ be associated with $q' = e^{6\pi i\tau} = q^{3}$. Then we have $$\eta(3\tau) = 2^{-1/6}\sqrt{\frac{2L}{\pi}}l^{1/12}l'^{1/3}\tag{3}$$ and $$\eta(6\tau) = 2^{-1/3}\sqrt{\frac{2L}{\pi}}(ll')^{1/6}\tag{4}$$ Beukers' paper talks about the function $$y(\tau) = \frac{\eta^{8}(6\tau)\eta^{4}(\tau)}{\eta^{8}(2\tau)\eta^{4}(3\tau)}\tag{5}$$ and mentions that it satisfies the following identity $$y(-1/6\tau) = \frac{y(\tau) - 1/9}{y(\tau) - 1}\tag{6}$$ Using the expression of $y(\tau)$ in terms of $\eta$ function and the functional equation $$\eta(-1/\tau) = \sqrt{-i\tau}\eta(\tau)\tag{7}$$ satisfied by the $\eta$ function we see that equation $(6)$ is equivalent to the following identity $$\frac{\eta^{8}(\tau)\eta^{4}(6\tau)}{\eta^{8}(3\tau)\eta^{4}(2\tau)} = \frac{9\eta^{8}(6\tau)\eta^{4}(\tau) - \eta^{8}(2\tau)\eta^{4}(3\tau)}{\eta^{8}(6\tau)\eta^{4}(\tau) - \eta^{8}(2\tau)\eta^{4}(3\tau)}\tag{8}$$ or $$\eta^{12}(\tau)\eta^{12}(6\tau) - \eta^{8}(\tau)\eta^{8}(2\tau)\eta^{4}(3\tau)\eta^{4}(6\tau) = 9\eta^{4}(\tau)\eta^{4}(2\tau)\eta^{8}(3\tau)\eta^{8}(6\tau) - \eta^{12}(2\tau)\eta^{12}(3\tau)$$ and using equations $(1)-(4)$ we can see that this is equivalent to $$\left(\frac{4KL}{\pi^{2}}\right)^{2}k'^{2}l - \left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right)^{4}kk'^{2} = 9\left(\frac{2L}{\pi}\right)^{4}ll'^{2} - \left(\frac{4KL}{\pi^{2}}\right)^{2}kl'^{2}$$ Using $m = K/L$ for multiplier we see that the above is equivalent to $$\frac{k'^{2}kl}{m^{2}} - k^{2}k'^{2} = \frac{9kll'^{2}}{m^{4}} - \frac{k^{2}l'^{2}}{m^{2}}\tag{9}$$ Now we know from [the theory of modular equations of degree $3$](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/02/elementary-approach-to-modular-equations-ramanujan-theory-6.html) that $$k^{2} = \frac{(m - 1)(3 + m)^{3}}{16m^{3}},\,l^{2} = \frac{(m - 1)^{3}(3 + m)}{16m}$$ and $$k'^{2} = \frac{(m + 1)(3 - m)^{3}}{16m^{3}},\,l'^{2} = \frac{(m + 1)^{3}(3 - m)}{16m}$$ so that $$kl = \frac{(m - 1)^{2}(3 + m)^{2}}{16m^{2}}$$ Putting the values of $k, l, k', l'$ in terms of $m$ we see (after some simple cancellations of factors on both sides of the equation $(9)$) that equation $(9)$ holds if we can establish $$(3 - m)^{2}(m - 1) - m(3 - m)^{2}(3 + m) = 9(m - 1)(m + 1)^{2} - m(3 + m)(m + 1)^{2}\tag{10}$$ Since each side is a polynomial of degree $4$ in $m$ it follows that the relation $(10)$ holds identically for all values of $m$ if it holds for at least $5$ distinct values of $m$. We can verify very easily that it holds for $m = 0, 1, -1, 3, -3$ and hence equation $(10)$ holds. Thus we have proved that $(9)$ also holds.

---

The approach given above is more of a verification of the identity $(6)$ which Beukers mentions in his paper. It is desirable to seek a proof based on some identity relating eta functions of argument $\tau, 2\tau, 3\tau$ or perhaps a proof based on theory of modular forms which shows directly that $y(-1/6\tau)$ is a rational function of $y(\tau)$.

Comment: @R.A.: It appears that you have been so motivated by "easy to show". I think Beukers' means that it is easy if one has good knowledge of theory of modular forms. I actually don't know much about modular forms, rather I am able to link various modular functions like $\eta$ with elliptic integrals $K$ and modulus $k, k'$ and transform identities between eta functions into identities between $k, k', K$. All this is part of a difficult theory of "elliptic integrals/functions and theta functions" and some part of it was later developed into theory of modular forms.

Comment: @R.A.: The meaning of "$y(\tau)$ generates a field" is something very different. Beukers wants to say that the field of rational expression in $y(\tau)$ also contains $y(-1/6\tau)$ and also gives an expression of $y(-1/6\tau)$ in terms of $y(\tau)$. But why this is the case needs a proof and the proof is non-trivial either by theory of modular forms (which I don't know) or by theory of theta functions (which I have given in my answer). Please don't get carried away by "easy to show" phrase written by Beukers.

Comment: @R.A.: Moreover if $x = y(\tau)$ then a rational expression in $x$ means a function of type $f(x)/g(x)$ where $f, g$ are polynomials. Thus he says that $y(-1/6\tau) = f(y(\tau))/g(y(\tau))$ for some some polynomials $f, g$. And coefficients of these polynomials are algebraic numbers.

Comment: @R.A.: It is not easy to find exact polynomials $f, g$ (and not possible via Fourier analysis). Beukers says that in this particular case $f(x) = x - (1/9)$ and $g(x) = x - 1$ but to get these expressions for $f, g$ is not as easy as Beukers' writes (definitely not easy without theory of modular forms). I suggest you study some theory of modular forms. And don't worry if you don't understand my solution. It also belongs to a difficult theory of elliptic integrals/functions and theta functions and not everyone is familiar with it.

Comment: If $\tau$ is interpreted as the elliptic period ratio, the rightmost sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$ give $\eta\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right)$ and $\eta(\tau)$ respectively. (The discrepancy may be due to the conflicting definitions for $q$ in use.) This does not invalidate the following reasoning because $\tau$ could be replaced with $2\tau$ everywhere. Nice proof. (I upvoted long ago, even before checking the details.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple proof using two eta product identities. If
$$ y_1(\tau) := \eta(2\tau)\eta^{9}(6\tau)\eta^{4}(\tau), \quad
 y_2(\tau) := \eta^{9}(2\tau)\eta^{4}(3\tau)\eta(6\tau), $$
then $\, y(\tau) = y_1(\tau)/y_2(\tau), \,$ and

$$ y_2(\tau) - 9y_1(\tau) = \eta(\tau)^9\eta(3\tau)\eta(6\tau)^4, \tag{1} $$

$$ y_2(\tau) -  y_1(\tau) = \eta(\tau)\eta(2\tau)^4\eta(3\tau)^9, \tag{2} $$

$$ y_3(\tau) := \frac{y_2(\tau) - 9y_1(\tau)}{y_2(\tau) -  y_1(\tau)}
     = 9\frac{y(\tau) - 1/9}{y(\tau) - 1}, \tag{3} $$

$$ y_3(\tau) =  9 \frac{\eta(\tau)^8 \eta(6\tau)^4}
{\eta(3\tau)^8 \eta(2\tau)^4}
     = y\Big(\frac{-1}{6\tau}\Big). \tag{4}$$

Equation $(1)$ is eta product identity $t_{6,13,30}$ multiplied by $\,\eta(6\tau)\,$
and equation $(2)$ is eta product identity $t_{6,13,34}$ multiplied by $\,\eta(2\tau).\,$
Both identities have many different forms and references to proofs were listed in
their entry in my Dedekind eta product identities website. The Wikipedia article [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function#References) links to the Wayback machine
where my website is archived.

Answer (score 0):

Identity (8) corresponds to an identity of Ramanujan proved by Berndt. "Ramanujan Notebooks", Part IV, p. 204, Entry 51.

Comment: The eta-product identity is $q_{6,24,60a}$ in my collection. The Ramanujan identity it is equivalent to is $(PQ)+9q/(PQ) = (Q/P)^3+q/(Q/P)^3$ where $P=(f(-q)/f(-q^3))^2, Q=(f(-q^2)/f(-q^6))^2$ and $f(-q)$ is a Ramanujan theta function, essentially $\eta(q)$ without the $q^{1/24}$ factor.